# How to call rest services from webpage passing json data for post method ,as we can do in advanced rest client

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

I want to call restful services from webpage passing json data for post method as we can do in as advanced rest client
.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating a service like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.myService', [])
.factory('MyService', [
  '$http',
  '$q',

  function($http, $q) {
    var service = {
      getJsonData: function getJsonData() {
        return $http.post("http://www.returnjsondata.com");
      }
    }

    return service;
  }
]);
```

Then in your controller, use the service like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.myController', [
  'myApp.myService'
])
.controller('MyController', [
  '$scope',
  'MyService',

  function($scope, MyService) {
    function callServiceToGetJsonData() {
      MyService.getJsonData()
        .success(function(response) {
          // The response returned should be the json data you're looking for
          // Use it however you like here.
        })
        .error(function(response) {
          // Error case
          console.log("Error calling the service!");
        });
    }
  }
]);
```

More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: What would be prerequisite to do this.I am new to angular js. What stuff should i know to do same as i can do in advanced rest client.